# Taking notes in a fantasy world that resembles our own early Renaissance?

Tags: language, renaissance

In a fantasy world that resembles the renaissance in our own world (let's say 1500-99 southern France) how might someone take notes on the go?

Would they have some parchment rolled up in their pant leg? What would they write with?

Would they have some sort of leather bound book that they carried in their sac?

To be more specific: they were once wealthy but now exiled from their home. Educated, so they could read and write. Now they take on odd jobs for day to day pay. When they collect these jobs, how might they take notes for themselves? (or would they at all?)

Comment: This belongs on the History stack as it is not about worldbuilding but actual history. many artists had sketchbooks just find out how they were made.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Parchment was very expensive, just like today. Parchment was never ever used for taking notes; only documents intended to be durable, or valuable books, were written on parchment.
2. They would most likely use paper, most likely in the form of a notebook. In those days, notebooks were seldom sold as such; everybody who went to school (not that many)  [learned at school](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notebook#Early_history) how to fold and bind blank paper sheets to make their own notebooks.

   [image: One of Leonardo da Vinci's notebooks]

   <sup>*One of Leonardo da Vinci's notebooks, late 15th century. Note the original cover! Picture from Wikimedia, by user Saiko, available under the GNU Free Documentation License, version 1.2 or later.*</sup>
3. They may also have used a [wax tablet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wax_tablet); however, the 16th century is quite a bit past the time of wax tablets. Maybe if they were in a very backwards region.
4. On paper, in the first half of the 16th century they may have written with a lead pencil (actual lead metal, it leaves a black trace on paper).

   In the second half of the 16th century graphite pencils came into use, after the discovery of the [Gray Knotts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grey_Knotts) mine in England.

   People who were professional or habitual note takers carried ink and [quills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quill) (= prepared goose feathers) for note taking; there are various designs for portable inkwells. Most intellectuals fall under this category. To adjust their quills, they would carry a small [penknife](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penknife) (which is why those small foldable knives are called *pen*knives). Everybody who went to school (not that many) learned at school how to prepare a quill and how to make their own [ink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_gall_ink).

   [image: European travelling inkwells][image: Ottoman portable writing set]

   <sup>*Left, European travelling inkwells. Right, Ottoman portable writing set (inkwell and pen boxes -- note that the Ottomans did not use quills, they used [reed qalams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qalam)). Pictures from Wikimedia, by user Palmiped and the Walters Art Musem respectively.*</sup>

Answer (score 3):

**Mnemonic notes**

Maybe your character is in a situation where he cannot easily stop what he is doing to take notes, or afford a notebook.  Or the notebook would attract attention, marking him as educated and he is keeping a low profile.  He could take mnemonic notes.

The classical mnemonic method is called the [Method of Loci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_loci) or the Roman Room.  It uses spatial memory in an imaginary space to help remember things.  Your educated protagonist may have been trained in these methods.

https://www.memnem.com/index.php/memnems-blog/35-pek-learning/54-mental-notes>

> The Roman Room. For thousands of years, people have been using Roman
>   Rooms to memorize long poems, Biblical text, and (in more recent
>   years) decks of cards in under a minute...
>
> The Roman Room is versatile and powerful because it uses your vast
>   spatial memory. Think about how easily you remember your house or your
>   route to work. Compare that to memorizing a list of dates. Spatial
>   memory allows you to memorize a lot more information quicker.
>
> Roman Rooms are easy to use. You simply take a well-known room and
>   walk through it in your mind, setting images you would like to
>   remember on different objects in your room. These memories are stored
>   away like papers in a filing cabinet. The Roman room is the filing
>   cabinet and the objects in the room are the different files.
>
> As you stroll through the room, you take memories, convert them into
>   images, and make these images interact with the room’s objects. This
>   allows you to come back to that room in your mind in order to remember
>   them anytime. Perhaps you want to remember to buy a carton of eggs. If
>   you imagine smashing that carton of eggs on your couch, you’ll find
>   that you can remember that memory whenever you think of your couch.
>   Try it out! See the dripping eggs and feel the disgusting, gooey mess
>   with your hands. What find is that it’s easy to remember this image
>   for the next 24 hours. In order to build a Roman Room, you can go
>   around a room and choose ten of these memory places. That means that
>   you’re able to store ten memories in every Roman Room.

This would make for engaging prose too - your character disappears into his mental Roman Room and lays down the memory in this space.  From the standpoint of the reader it would be like he briefly visited another dimension.  There are other things in that room which he has placed previously.  Outlandish or unusual things are better as regards being remembered - also god for prose.

Comment: Quoting a random modern text when we have splendid descriptions of this mnemonic technique from the antiquity? For example, [Quintilian 11:2](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/Quintilian/Institutio_Oratoria/11B*.html): *"It is an assistance to the memory if localities are sharply impressed upon the mind, a view the truth of which everyone may realise by practical experiment. For when we return to a place after considerable absence, we [...] remember things that we did there, and recall [...] the unuttered thoughts which passed through our minds when we were there"* etc.